# RHEL5 Linux ODBC Issues

Tags: c, linux, unix, odbc, rhel5

Am trying to move my compiled C code that connects to mssql database servers from using the datadirect odbc drivers to using the unixodbc driver manager (version  2.3.1)/
freetds drivers (version 0.91) which are already compiled for 64 bit and available.

Am able to successfully compile it on 64 bit RHEL5 Linux by linking in  libodbc which has already been compiled. But I get the error `net.c:350: tds_select: 
Assertion 'timeout_seconds >= 0' failed` multiple times when I run the code and the database connection fails. The environment variables I set are `ODBCINI`, `ODBCHOME` and `LDD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which is set to the libraries in the unixodbc path).

The driver in the odbcinst file is set to the path where libtdsodbc.so is located.

Am I missing something here. The permissions on the `odbc.ini`, `odbcinst.ini` files appear to be fine.

Comment: Just a guess here (I spend far more time with PHP than I do with C nowadays) - have you modified your /etc/freetds/freetds.conf file? Is your executable aware of this conf file - do you need to set another environment variable for it?

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. Does not work. Any other suggestions

Comment: I'm afraid not. Based on my freetds.conf file I would assume FreeTDS has a default timeout of 10 seconds so unless you've put something in the conf file like `timeout = 0` I don't know why the assertion would fail.